# Closed Poincaré dual, why $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$ and not $\int_M \eta_S \wedge \omega $?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, integration

My book is Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology by Loring W. Tu and Raoul Bott of which An Introduction to Manifolds by Loring W. Tu is a prequel.

The characterization of the closed Poincaré dual is given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSgf9.png) (the "(5.13)") in Section 5.5. This has $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$, where $\eta_S$ is on the **right rather than left**.

**Question**: Why is it $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$, where $\eta_S$ is on the **right rather than left**?

- See below for why I think $\eta_S$ should be on the **left rather than right**.
- Previously, in Section 5.3, we had [this equivalent definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4hX.png) (the "Lemma") of a nondegenerate pairing between two finite-dimensional vector spaces and [Poincaré duality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4hX.png) (the "(5.4)").
- Note: I believe the characterization for compact Poincaré dual for compact $S$ and $M$ of finite type is correct with $\eta_S'$ on the right.
- Guess: Could have something to do with sign commutativity of Mayer-Vietoris, as described in [Lemma 5.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wb8JT.png).
- Guess: Poincare dual as described is indeed with $\eta_S$ on the left, but there's also a unique cohomology class $[\gamma_S]$ that's on the right given by $[\gamma_S] = [-\eta_S]$.

---

**How I got $\int_M \eta_S \wedge \omega$ instead of $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$**:

I use $()^{\vee}$, instead of $()^{*}$, to denote dual just like in [Section 3.1 of the prequel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEbs1.png).

1. Let $\varphi$ be the "linear functional on $H^{k}_cM$" given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSgf9.png).

   - Such $\varphi: H^{k}_cM \to \mathbb R$ is given by $\varphi[\omega] = \int_S \iota^{*}\omega$ for $[\omega] \in H^k_cM$ and $\iota: S \to M$ inclusion.
2. Let $\delta$ be the isomorphism of [Poincaré duality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4hX.png) (the "(5.4)").

   - Such $\delta: H^{n-k}M \to (H^{k}_cM)^{\vee}$ is given by $\delta([\tau]) = \delta_{[\tau]}$, for $[\tau] \in H^{n-k}M$ and $\delta_{[\tau]}$ given below.
   - $\delta_{[\tau]}([\omega]) = \int_M (\tau \wedge \omega)$, for $[\omega] \in H^k_cM$, under the well-definedness described in [Section 24.4 of the prequel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acEp1.png) (which I think is the full details of the "Because the wedge product is an antiderivation, it descends to cohomology" [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4hX.png)) and under the pairing given [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW4hX.png), which I believe puts $\tau$ on the **left rather than right**.
3. $[\eta_S]$ is the inverse image of $\varphi$ under  $\delta$.

   - By choosing $[\tau] = [\eta_S]$, we get $\delta([\eta_S]) = \delta_{[\eta_S]} = \varphi$, that is, for all $[\omega] \in H^k_cM$,

$$\int_M (\eta_S \wedge \omega) = \int_S \iota^{*}\omega,$$

where $\eta_S$ is on the **left rather than right**.

---

**Edit**: After doing some thinking (it's easier to think when you know something is right/wrong as opposed to thinking about whether or not it's right/wrong, I believe), along with comments of Najib Idrissi and answer of Prof Tu, I think I've got it. Is this right?

We get a unique class $[\gamma_S]$ where for $\gamma_S \in [\gamma_S]$ (or any other element of $[\gamma_S]$), we have that for all $[\omega] \in H^k_cM$ $\omega \in [\omega]$ (or any other element of $[\omega]$),

$$\int_M (\gamma_S \wedge \omega) = \int_M ((-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k}\omega \wedge \gamma_S) = \int_M (\omega \wedge (-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k} \gamma_S) = \int_S \iota^{*}\omega$$ and then define $[\eta_S] := (-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k} [\gamma_S] := [(-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k} \gamma_S]$.

In this case, I think $[\eta_S] := - [\gamma_S] := [-\gamma_S]$ is a different definition from the one in the preceding paragraph unless $k(n-k)$ is an odd integer or something.

Comment: This makes very little difference... If you put $\tau$ on the right in the definition of $\delta$ then it's slightly more consistent, yes.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Do you really mean $\tau$ and not $\eta_S$? I actually think the one with $\tau$ is correct

Comment: I don't see why putting it on the left would be correct and on the right would be incorrect. In the end you're just changing a sign... The probable answer for "Why?" is certainly that the book is more than 300 pages long and this is an inconsequential oversight.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Wait so it's really a mistake? That's all I needed: either it's a mistake or I misunderstood somehow.

Comment: "Mistake" is rather excessive for what it is.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi 1. What do you mean then? 2. My derivation for the closed Poincaré dual gives me $\eta_S$ on the left rather than right. Am I wrong? 3. The book's derivation gives $\eta_S$ on the right rather than left. Is that book wrong? 4. If you answered no to both (2) and (3), then do you mean $$\int_M (\eta_S \wedge \omega) = \int_S \iota^{*}\omega$$ holds for each $\omega$ if and only if $$ \int_M (\omega \wedge  \eta_S) = \int_S \iota^{*}\omega$$ holds of reach $\omega$? I guess this is by substitution like $\int_0^1 x dx = \int_{-1}^0 -x dx$?

Comment: I mean that yes, it is a mistake. And I mean that it is of no consequence. "Oversight", as I said, is more appropriate.

Comment: For the record, I think reading a value judgement into 'mistake' is (well) a mistake.  If there is a typo on p. 363 of an otherwise-perfect Serre manuscript, say, then I would call it a mistake, but not mean any slight by it.  I suspect the authors themselves would cheerfully call this an easily fixed mistake.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I think this mistake may have consequences for compact Poincaré dual. Please help. [Closed Poincaré dual is $\int_M \eta_S \wedge \omega $ and not $\int_M \omega \wedge \eta_S$. What about the compact Poincaré dual?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/333287/closed-poincar%C3%A9-dual-is-int-m-eta-s-wedge-omega-and-not-int-m-omega-w)

Comment: @SeleneAuckland You realize that all it changes is a sign, right? In your other question, it's then $-\eta_S$ which is the closed Poincaré dual.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Thanks, but I think I'm confused by these mini-answer comments. I hope you could please clarify with a direct answer in an answer post. 1. So (5.13) is supposed to have $\eta_S$ on the left rather than the right? Please answer directly with a yes or no. 2. For (5.14), the compact Poincaré dual is not the closed Poincaré dual but rather the negative of the closed Poincaré dual?

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Edited question. Do we have $[\eta_S] := (-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k} [\gamma_S] := [(-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k} \gamma_S]$ rather than $[\eta_S] := [- \gamma_S]$? Or is $k(n-k)$ somehow odd?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A definition is what one makes it to be.  Sometimes there are choices and it is difficult to say whether one choice is more correct than another.  There is virtue in consistency.  In the discussion of Poincaré duality in DFAT, I put forms with no restrictions before forms with compact support.  To be consistent with this, $\eta_S$ should be placed before (to the left of) $\omega \in H_c^k(M)$ and the closed Poincaré dual of a compact submanifold $S$ would be $\pm$ the compact Poincaré dual.  However, one might decide to have the closed Poincaré dual equal to exactly the compact Poincaré dual.  In this case, $\eta_S$ would be written after (to the right of) $\omega \in H_c^k(M)$.  This was the choice I made.  I don't think it is incorrect.

Comment: Welcome to MO, Professor Tu!

Comment: Thanks! Oh wait I think I get it now, Prof Tu. Do you mean $[\eta_S] := (-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k} [\gamma_S] := [(-1)^{k} (-1)^{n-k} \gamma_S]$? Please see my edit to my question.

Comment: Thanks Prof Tu!

Comment: This is a response to Selena Auckland's edit of August 5 '19.  When a k-form and an (n-k)-form are exchanged in a wedge product, the resulting sign is $(-1)^{k(n-k)}$, not $(-1)^k (-1)^{n-k}$.  Otherwise, I think your edit is correct.

Comment: @LoringTu Does the computation of Thom class using normal bundle in section 6 coincide with the orientation？